# angular component is not a known element after using constructor

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I have *custom component* referred in my `app.component.html`. If I add any argument to the constructor of that *custom component* I get the error:

> 'component' is not a known element

I want to use a service inside the *custom component*, that is why I need to add `private readonly headerService: HeaderService`

**The site render without any problems, I only see the error on visual code, ng serve don't give any response.**

#### headerService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeaderService {
  constructor() {}
}
```

#### component with constructor argument

[image]

#### component without constructor argument

[image]

#### ng version

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.12
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.12
@angular/cdk                    11.2.12
@angular/cli                    11.2.12
@angular/material               11.2.12
@schematics/angular             11.2.12
@schematics/update              0.1102.12
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.1.5
```

Comment: Can you make stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Looks like you didn't declare the component in the module. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules

Comment: @KiranMistry I tried already to reproduce it on stackblitz. I was not able to. This small [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9dmesa?file=src/app/app.module.ts) would produce the error in my environment.
@AlvinSaldanha unfortunately I declare the component in the module (`\src\app\app.module.ts`):  ```@NgModule({ declarations: [ AppComponent, NavComponent, PageHeaderComponent, ... ]```

Comment: Is the import right? The path seems a little strange.

Comment: @NicholasK sorry, I misleading you. That is a relativ path, not an import. My import looks like `import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';` for example in `main.ts`

Comment: Sorry, I meant in `HeaderService` - is that import right?

Comment: If you mean `Import { HeaderService } from 'src/app/service/header.service';` I don't know if it's wrong. It get automatically added by visual code.

Comment: Usually, import paths don't start with `src/...`, its a relative path something like `../../header.service`.

Comment: I know, I was wondering before about the same thing. But I don't know why visual code/angular insert `Imports` like this. :/